# How do I replace a function, declared inside a plugin's class, in functions.php?

Tags: plugins, functions, include

I want to modify a function in a plugin. It is declared in the plugin's main file like this:

```
class WCPGSK_Main {
  ...
  public function wcpgsk_email_after_order_table($order) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Add called from there like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array($this, 'wcpgsk_email_after_order_table') );
```

I guess it would be possible to replace it if had an access to the class in functions.php. Then I would be able to write something like this:

```
$wcpgsk = new WCPGSK_Main;

remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array($wcpgsk, 'wcpgsk_email_after_order_table') );

function customized_wcpgsk_email_after_order_table($order) {
  ...
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array($wcpgsk, 'customized_wcpgsk_email_after_order_table') );
```

My thought to get an access to the class in the functions.php file was to include the file where the class is declared in functions.php:

```
require_once('/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife.php');
$wcpgsk = new WCPGSK_Main;
...
```

But this does not work because the plugin's file is included when the plugin is getting initialized in WordPress, I guess.

Is there a way to rewrite the function without touching plugin's files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'remove_wcpgsk_email_order_table' );
function remove_wcpgsk_email_order_table() {

    global $wcpgsk;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $wcpgsk, 'wcpgsk_email_after_order_table' ) );

}
```

Comment: there is a remove_action function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: Yes, that's I missed, this plugin has a variable which can accessed as a global one. My stupidity. Thanks for your answer, this is working in this particular case (for this plugin).

Comment: Alex Older linked to the place that explains why his answer works. The remove_action accepts an array with the static or instance class within which you wish to remove a method.

Answer (score 12):

If your plugin is registered like this:

```
class Test_Class_Parent {
  function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_head',array($this,'test_method'));
  }

  function test_method() {
    echo 'Echoed from the parent';
  }
}
$p = new Test_Class_Parent();
```

Then you should be able to remove the filter by accessing the global:

```
class Test_Class_Child extends Test_Class_Parent {
  function __construct() {
    $this->unregister_parent_hook();
    add_action('wp_head',array($this,'test_method'));
  }

  function unregister_parent_hook() {
    global $p;
    remove_action('wp_head',array($p,'test_method'));
  }

  function test_method() {
    echo 'Echoed from the child';
  }
}
$c = new Test_Class_Child();
```

Otherwise, you will need to crawl the `$wp_filter` `global` for the registration key:

```
class Test_Class_Child extends Test_Class_Parent {
  function __construct() {
    $this->unregister_parent_hook();
    add_action('wp_head',array($this,'test_method'));
  }

  function unregister_parent_hook() {
    global $wp_filter;
    if (!empty($wp_filter['wp_head'])) {
      foreach($wp_filter['wp_head'] as $cb) {
        foreach ($cb as $k => $v) {
          if (
            isset($v['function'])
            && is_a($v['function'][0],'Test_Class_Parent')
            && isset($v['function'][1])
            && 'test_method' == $v['function'][1]
          ) {
            remove_action('wp_head',$k);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function test_method() {
    echo 'Echoed from the child';
  }
}
$c = new Test_Class_Child();
```

This is resource intensive and should really not be done unless you have no other choice.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  This is more generally useful, and not limited to just OP's specific case.

Answer (score 1):

That plugin makes its init function `wcpgsk_init()` pluggable, so another way to override it is to define it first in a must-use plugin (as it's too late in your theme's "functions.php"). So you could put your override in "wp-content/mu-plugins/functions.php":

```
function wcpgsk_init() {
    global $wcpgsk, $wcpgsk_about, $wcpgsk_options, $wcpgsk_session, $wcpgsk_woocommerce_active;    
    //only continue loading
    if ( $wcpgsk_woocommerce_active && version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, "2.0" ) >= 0 ) {
        $FILE = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife.php'; // Fake __FILE__
        $dirname = dirname( $FILE ) . '/';
        $wcpgsk_options = get_option('wcpgsk_settings', true);
        require_once( $dirname . 'classes/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife.php' );
        require_once( $dirname . 'classes/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife-about.php' );   
        require_once( $dirname . 'wcpgsk-af.php' );

        if ( !is_admin() ) :
            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wcpgsk_load_wcsession_helper' );
        endif;

        // Your override.
        class My_WCPGSK_Main extends WCPGSK_Main {
            public function wcpgsk_email_after_order_table($order) {
                echo "O la la";
            }
        }
        define( 'WCRGSK_DOMAIN', WCPGSK_DOMAIN ); // Fix typo! (WooCommerce Rich Guys Swiss Knife?)

        //load into our global
        $wcpgsk = new My_WCPGSK_Main( $FILE );
        $wcpgsk->version = '2.2.4'; 
        $wcpgsk->wcpgsk_hook_woocommerce_filters();


    } elseif ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, "2.0" ) < 0 ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wcpgsk_woocommerce_version_message', 0 ) ;    
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

But an even better way to override it is to install `runkit` (https://github.com/padraic/runkit) and then just replace it directly in your theme's "functions.php":

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    $code = <<<'EOD'
echo "O la la";
EOD;
    runkit_method_redefine(
        'WCPGSK_Main',
        'wcpgsk_email_after_order_table',
        '$order',
        $code,
        RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC
    );
} );
```

(That's a joke, btw.)